# Sort java script array of formatted date

Tags: javascript

I have an javascript array of date which is formatted in a particular way like MM/DD/YYYY. How can I use  javascript sort function to sort this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), but you need to pass a custom comparison function which converts the values to `Date`s and compares those, instead of just the string value:

```js
var arr = ['07/01/2014', '04/02/2014', '12/11/2013'];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    // convert both arguments to a date
    var da = new Date(a);
    var db = new Date(b);

    // do standard comparison checks
    if(da < db) {
        return -1;
    } else if(da > db) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

// print the result
var result = document.getElementById('result');
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
    result.value = result.value + '\n' + arr[i];
}
```

```html
<textarea id="result" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the dates stored as strings or as Date objects? You can convert each string into a date object by using the Date constructor like `new Date('MM/DD/YYYY')`. This will give you Date objects and make it much easier to compare. To compare Dates and sort them, just grab their values using the `getTime()` function to get their value in milliseconds and compare the numbers.